# vb.net and html parsing

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, xpath

Currently I'm using the IHTMLDocument2 and IHTMLElementCollection to parse HTML, is there some way to parse it using some sort of xpath/selectors, something like

```
elements = find_html_elements("a .link[rel=100]") ?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download and use the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it supports Xpath.